# IoTHubTrigger Azure Function does not trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have an Azure function with the following signature:

```
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    [return: EventHub("eventhubname", Connection = "EVENTHUB_OUTPUT_CONNECTIONSTRING")]
    public static string Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "IOTHUB_CONNECTIONSTRING", ConsumerGroup = "consumergroup")] EventData message, ILogger log)
```

I am running another Azure Functions with HTTP trigger. When i post to this function, it sends a device message to IoThub. I can see the message coming into the IoT Hub.

My routes have been setup as follows:

[image]

My routes have no special queries and i can see them hitting all the endpoints.

I have used the connectionstring from this page:

[image]

When i run in debug and when published to Azure, my function does not trigger when sending device messages. I have created 2 consumer groups and I am running 2 partitions.

Any idea what i could change to make this work?

Comment: Did you set the connection string in Azure as well somehow?

Comment: I assume `EVENTHUB_OUTPUT_CONNECTIONSTRING` points to an app setting and you are not putting in your connection string directly in there

Comment: Is there any chance that anything else (including whatever you are using to watch the messages hit IoT Hub) is also listening on the 'consumergroup' consumer group?

Comment: All connection strings are in the env variables both locally and on azure. If the connection strings would be wrong or not available, the debugger tells me this. Before, I had it working but when i changed the name of the consumer group, it stopped working. I am the sole developer and there cannot be other clients listening in. But i will try with 2 different consumer group names, that is a good suggestion! Thanks